# API, showing results twice and not in correct order

Tags: api, drupal

For the first time I'm creating a API to import data to a swift App (iOS)
But I get all my results twice and the results don't know where the belong or are in the wrong order...

I think it's because I have several tables I'm pulling from.

an example:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM node, field_data_body";
//Drupal tables

I have heard about the WHERE statement, but got no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is a [implicit cross JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), as you select from multiple tables. Without using conditions in your WHERE clause, you had all combinations of those tables.

If your tables are fully separate/independent, you can create 2 different SELECT queries for each of tables.

Otherwise, if there is a relationship between them, you should select one of the JOIN types, that is most appropriate for your goal, and describe his relationship in query using WHERE conditions.

Lets assume that node table has "id" column, and field_data_body has "node_id" column. Then query can be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM node 
LEFT JOIN field_data_body ON node.id = field_data_body.node_id
```

or the same

```
SELECT * FROM node 
LEFT JOIN field_data_body WHERE node.id = field_data_body.node_id
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) is a good visual representations of SQL JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's recommended to use the Entity API to query data from Drupal, and here is a document, https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

And you can also set up your query with View module, and set the output to JSON.

The third option could be using https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_server module.

Comment: Thx all, I learned a great deal with this.
The solution in my case is:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM node 
LEFT JOIN field_data_body ON node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id";

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the tables `node` and `field_data_body` contain the same data? Your `selecte * from` statement would take everything, if it's not distinct.

Comment: The field_date_body does have an entity_type (node).... hmm maybe you are on to something AMomchilov, how would one work around this issue?

Comment: Well I can't tell you much given what you've told me, or rather, haven't. IDK what data you have, nor what data you want.